# Do I need to align my tires after replacing the struts?

Tags: camry, alignment, struts

I just replaced all 4 struts in my 2002 Camry. I'm about to put the tires back on, but am I good to drive off or do I need to do alignment first? I know how to check my front toe if my rear wheels are parallel already using the string method, but if nothing is aligned I'm not sure where to get started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you do need to get them aligned. You'll be OK driving it to the garage to have it done.